# Making rate limit requests to cursor paginated api using asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, httprequest, python-asyncio

I'm trying to get data from an API that allows to make 4 requests per second. I'd like to use asyncio in order to get the data but I can't seem to find a way to use it properly.

This is what I have so far:

```
async def fetch_request(self, url):
    async with self.rate_limiter:
        data = requests.get(url)
        return data['items'], data['next']

async def collect_data(self, urls):
    data = []
    for url in urls:
        items, next_cursor = await self.fetch_request(url)
        data.append(items)
        
        while next_cursor:
            items, next_cursor = await self.fetch_request(url)
            data.append(items)
    
    return data

class fetchUrls(self):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    urls = [] #list of urls
    self.rate_limiter = RateLimiter(max_calls=4, period=1)
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(self.collect_data(urls)))
```

Basically I first generate a list of urls that I want to request. Each of those requests can return (besides data) a cursor for the next page, that's the main problem I'm having to deal with.

I'm using a library https://github.com/RazerM/ratelimiter to handle the rate limiting part.

Right now I'm getting `TypeError: expect a list of futures, not coroutine`.

Comment: Any feedback please ?

Comment: Hello, in addition I decided to develop my own package which will provide ratelimiters based on bucket conception. I'll be happy if you check it. https://github.com/ArtyomKozyrev8/BucketRateLimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed the following library to solve the problem [BucketRateLimiter](https://github.com/ArtyomKozyrev8/BucketRateLimiter) you can check it to solve your issue.

Also you can solve the problem the following way without any 3rd party library:

```py
import asyncio
from typing import Awaitable, Any, NamedTuple
from random import randint
from datetime import datetime
import time


TASKS = [(i, i, i) for i in range(20)]  # imagine it is URLs
WORKER_NUM = 1000


class BucketTimeRateLimiter:
    def __init__(
            self,
            max_size: int = 4,
            recovery_time: float = 1.0,
            rest_time: float = 0.2,
    ) -> None:
        """
        The Bucket is used to limit number of "simultaneous" operations to specified number.
        :param max_size: max size of Bucket, max "simultaneous" number of operations
        :param recovery_time: time to recover Bucket to full size
        :param rest_time: time to give "workers" who use bucket to sleep
        """
        self.max_size = max_size
        self.active_slots = max_size  # number of active slots at the moment
        self.recovery_time = recovery_time
        self.rest_time = rest_time
        # used to signal "external" workers that bucket is "empty"
        self.event = asyncio.Event()

    def _decrement(self) -> None:
        """Decrements internal counter self.active_slots."""
        if self.active_slots > 0:
            self.active_slots -= 1

    async def _reactivate_slots(self) -> None:
        """Every n seconds (self.recovery_time) refresh number of self.active_slots to max number."""
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(self.recovery_time)
            self.active_slots = self.max_size
            self.event.set()

    async def wrap_operation(self, func: Awaitable, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        """Wrapper around some async function. It limits number of "simultaneous" ops."""
        while True:
            if self.event.is_set():  # if bucket is not empty do work
                if self.active_slots == 0:
                    self.event.clear()
                else:
                    self._decrement()
                    res = await func(*args, **kwargs)
                    return res
            else:
                await asyncio.sleep(self.rest_time)

    def activate(self) -> None:
        """The method "activates" our Bucket logic."""
        self.event.set()  # set event flag that bucket is ready
        asyncio.create_task(self._reactivate_slots())


class TestResult(NamedTuple):
    """Result of our "fetch" function """
    res: int
    start: str
    end: str


async def some_func(x: int, y: int, z: int) -> TestResult:
    """Imagine it is a fetch function."""
    format_time = "%H:%M:%S"
    start = datetime.utcnow().strftime(format_time)
    await asyncio.sleep(randint(1, 1))  # wait exactly 1 second :)
    end = datetime.utcnow().strftime(format_time)
    result = x

    return TestResult(result, start, end)


async def worker(q: asyncio.Queue, bucket: BucketTimeRateLimiter) -> None:
    """Workers which do some stuff."""
    while True:
        item = await q.get()
        res: TestResult = await bucket.wrap_operation(some_func, *item)
        print(f"Result: {res.res} | {res.start} - {res.end}")
        q.task_done()


async def main_entry_point() -> None:
    """Main entry point of our asyncio app."""
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    bucket = BucketTimeRateLimiter()
    for task in TASKS:
        await q.put(task)  # send all tasks to the Queue

    bucket.activate()  # run "daemon" task
    for w in [worker(q, bucket) for _ in range(1, WORKER_NUM + 1)]:
        asyncio.create_task(w)  # run as "daemon" task

    await q.join()  # wait until all task in queue were done

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_t = time.monotonic()
    asyncio.run(main_entry_point())
    print(f"Time passed: {time.monotonic() - start_t}")
```